# Take out the only element of a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, filtering

I have a repeatedly nested one-element list, e.g. `a={{{{2}}}}`. Is there a direct way to pull out the innermost element? I could just do `First@Flatten@a`, but I feel like there should be an even more straightforward method.

Comment: `Max@a` perhaps?

Comment: @wxffles Using `Max` on an empty (nested) list such as `Max@{{}}` returns `-\[Infinity]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`First@Flatten@a` can be be annoying since `Flatten` fails for atomic expressions e.g. when you have non-nested expressions too e.g.

```
list={{{1}}, {2}, {{{3}}}, 4}
First@*Flatten /@ list
(* Flatten::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Flatten[4]. *)
```

if you want to avoid this you could for instance use

```
Apply[Sequence, #, All] & /@ list
```

**Edit:** 
In response to Kuba's comment I though a little more about this and found another "special case" that fails when naively using `First@Flatten@a`

```
First@Flatten@{{{}}}
(* First::nofirst: {} has zero length and no first element. *)
```

An empty (nested) list might occur in the context of flattening some result returned by another function where there is a possibly of not having found a solution/partial solution.

`Apply[Sequence, {{{}}}, All]` one the other hand simply evaluates to `Sequence[]` which vanishes upon further evaluation. Another fix for this is of course the new second argument to `First`

```
First[#, Nothing[]]&@Flatten@{{{}}}
```

Comment: But then the input isn't really a nested list.

Comment: @Kuba I know, but more often than not I end up using something like `First@Flatten@a` inside some more complex context and have it fail later in some special cases (such as atomic expressions which could one view as being nested with depth 0).

Answer (score 1):

Probably a matter of taste:

```
a /. List -> (# &)
```

I'd go with your method though.

If that element does not have "a structure" you can use e.g. `Level[a, {-1}][[1]]` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to wrap up the solutions:

- if one considers repeatedly nested single-element lists, e.g. `{{{2}}}`, then `Max` returns the innermost element; this works also for non-numerical elements like `a` or `"a"`;
- when the innermost list is empty, `{{{}}}`, then `Max` returns `-∞`, which may cause problems;
- `First@Flatten` gives an error when used on an empty nested list;
- the safest possibility seems to be to define a new function, `elem := First[#, Nothing[]] &@Flatten@#1 &`, that works on empty as well as non-empty single-element nested lists - credit for this goes to [Sascha](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126291/22013).

I did not consider here lists with more than one element, e.g. `{{{1,{a}}}}`; `Max` remains unevaluated (unless `a` is also numerical, but then it just gives the greater element), while `First@Flatten` and `elem` return the first element, i.e. `1` in this case. But such lists are not the scope of this question as how to handle them will be different in each  particular situation.